PIP installing lowest possible version of dependency without explanation
AFAIK, pip's default behavior is to install latest released versions of subdependencies, which satisfy all requirements. However, I'm observing quite the opposite behavior when trying to install my project afresh.
Here's my requirements.txt (it does beg for some stricter version specification, I know):
datasets>=2.14.2
rouge-score>=0.0.4
nlpaug>=1.1.10
scikit-learn>=1.5.1
tqdm>=4.64.1
matplotlib>=3.6
pandas>=1.3.5
torch>=1.13.0
bs4
transformers>=4.40
nltk>=3.6.5
sacrebleu>=1.5.0
sentencepiece>=0.1.97
hf-lfs>=0.0.3
pytest>=4.4.1
pytreebank>=0.2.7
setuptools>=60.2.0
numpy>=1.23.5
dill>=0.3.5.1
scipy>=1.9.3
flask>=2.3.2
protobuf>=4.23
fschat>=0.2.3
hydra-core>=1.3.2
einops
accelerate>=0.32.1
bitsandbytes
openai>=1.52.0
wget
sentence-transformers
bert-score>=0.3.13
unbabel-comet==2.2.1
nltk>=3.7,<4
evaluate>=0.4.2
spacy>=3.4.0,<4
fastchat
diskcache>=5.6.3

This is excrept from what I see when running pip install -e . in the project directory with a fresh conda env:
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib>=3.6->lm_polygraph==0.0.0)
  Using cached contourpy-1.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.7-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)

This happens to several sub-dependencies and might take a while, if no cache is present on the machine, and eventually installs the ancient versions of the packages. Why would it do that, if the first option it tries seems to satisfy the requirements? Running pip with -vvv doesn't specify why it tries lower versions either.
Some context:
python --version
Python 3.10.0
pip --version
pip 24.2 from /apps/local/anaconda3/envs/polygraph_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

pip debug output:
https://pastebin.com/NkJ9qbPG
Full install log:
https://pastebin.com/u8RY3pEp
UPD: weirdly enough, it installs latest versions eventually:
pip list | grep contour
contourpy                1.3.0

But tries all the versions between lowest satisfying and latest available, which takes a lot of time for something like transformers, for which it tries to download all versions between 4.40 and 4.46.

Please [edit] the Q and show us the text output of pip debug

@phd uploaded to pastebin and linked in the question.

Tangential to the question itself, but I'd recommend trying uv for a package installer. It's much faster, especially in a loosely pinned case.

@Roman pip debug looks good. No idea what is goiing on. pip3.10 install contourpy downloaded and installed contourpy-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl, no problem.
